# viewWillAppear delay in update table from webservices

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, web-services

Is viewWillAppear the best place in the lifecycle to import my data from a webservice? This relates to a small exchange rate app.

In a tableview from viewwillappear, we go to http://api.fixer.io to update an array called rates, and all of the returned data in a class RatesData. If the Internet connection fails we either use the data we already have, or look to a file on the phone file system.

The time it takes to import the data means that I run cellForRowAt indexPath before my data array is populated; meaning that the data appears after a perceptible delay (I've default cells to load) before being updated with exchange rates.

I will implement coredata next as a better solution but the first time the app runs we would still get this undesired effect.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    searchForRates()
    importCountriessync()
}


private func searchForRates(){
    Request.fetchRates(withurl: APIConstants.eurURL) {[weak self]  (newData:RatesData, error:Error?)->Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //update table on the main queue
            //returns array of rates
            guard (error == nil) else {
                print ("did not recieve data - getting from file if not already existing")
                if ( self?.rates == nil)
                {
                    self?.searchForFileRates()
                }
                return

            }
            self?.rates = newData.rates
            let newData = RatesData(base: newData.base, date: Date(), rates: newData.rates)
            self?.ratesFullData = newData
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}


func searchForFileRates(){
    print ("file rates")
    Request.fetchRates(withfile: "latest.json") { [weak self] (newData: RatesData)->Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //update table on the main queue
            //returns array of rates
            self?.rates = newData.rates
            let newData = RatesData(base: newData.base, date: Date(), rates: newData.rates)
            self?.ratesFullData = newData
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `super.viewWillAppear(animated)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes `viewWillAppear` is fine as long as the fetch is **asynchronous**.
- Just remember it will be fired every time the view appears. Example when this view controller is hidden by another modal view controller and the modal view controller is dismissed, `viewWillAppear` will be called. If you want it to be called only once you could invoke it in `viewDidLoad`

## Summary

- `viewWillAppear` - Invoked every time view appears
- `viewDidLoad` - Invoked once when the view first loads
- Choose what meets your needs.